# How can I split this array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

Noob question.  I have this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => address = 123 Something Street
    [1] => address2 = Something else
    [2] => city = Kalamazoo
    [3] => state = MI
    [4] => zip = 49097
    [5] => country = United States
)
```

but I want this:

```
Array
(
    [address] => 123 Something Street
    [address2] => Something else
    [city] => Kalamazoo
    [state] => MI
    [zip] => 49097
    [country] => United States
)
```

How do I do this?  Thanks!

Comment: -1 Your question demonstrates a clear lack of research effort and no attempts to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @rdlowrey Your comment is presumptuous.  I am a beginner and I actually did work hard to try to figure this out on my own but could not do it.  Thanks for making a newbie feel stupid.

Comment: If you *"work[ed] hard"*, show evidence of that labor in the question. Don't shoot the messenger. This is what the downvote button is for. Read, understand and implement the suggestions at [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and you'll never get downvoted again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($your_array as $line) {
 list($key, $value) = explode('=', $line, 2);
 $new_array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Access `$new_array`.

Comment: Slight addition, if you pass `2` as the third parameter to `explode`, it will only return two pieces so there can be `=` in the values.

Comment: Yeah, I like that, will add that now.

Comment: You could also add `trim()` to `$key` and `$value` to prevent whitespace

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I was trying to use explode on the '=' but could not get the key and value part figured out.  Looks like list() is what i needed.  Thx again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the array and break up the value into the bit before the ' = ' and the bit after. using these two pieces of data you can create a new array which is indexed by the first bit and has the value as the second bit.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($your_array as $value)
{
    $chunks = explode(' = ', $value);
    $key = $chunks[0];
    $new_array[$key] = $chunks[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayOriginal = Array
(
    [0] => address = 123 Something Street
    [1] => address2 = Something else
    [2] => city = Kalamazoo
    [3] => state = MI
    [4] => zip = 49097
    [5] => country = United States
);
$arrayNew = Array();
for($arrayOriginal as $value)
{
    $strArray = explode(" = ", $value, 2);
    $arrayNew[$strArray[0]] = $stArray[1];
}
```

A small thing to note, if your array is not likely to be exactly formatted, instead do:

```
for($arrayOriginal as $value)
{
    $strArray = explode("=", $value, 2);
    $arrayNew[trim($strArray[0])] = trim($strArray[1]);
}
```

This ensures that even values like "something      =       something" will be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any function to do this automatically for you, but I just wrote up the following.

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($oldArr as $value) {
    $split = explode(" = ", $value, 2);
    $newArr[$split[0]] = $split[1];
}
```